# Downgrade magento 2 version

Tags: magento2, magento-2.2.1, magento2.2.0

I excidently upgraded the magento version from 2.2.0 to 2.2.1 through composer. Is there a proper way to downgrade back to 2.2.0? I have a database backup of magento 2.2.0.

Comment: Have you tried as per my answer?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and Magento2 doesn't support roll-back completely.

**What to do:-**

- First of all, you have to make your code to 2.2.0. You can do that by using composer.

> ```
> composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.2.0 --no-update
>
> composer update
> ```

- If you have a DB copy of your Magento 2.2.0 than link current app [2.2.0] to it and run upgrade. It will bring your 2.2.1 DB to 2.2.0 and you will be in sync again.